# Excel Pivot Table- Top 8 tasks

Tags: excel, pivot

I have to sort the top 8 tasks for every month. When I try to use the value filters option for top n its showing top 8 tasks cumulatively for all the months.

I need to show top 8 for respective months (for every row).

Can you guys help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a date field, just filter the dates. I would create a new column using the formula: `=Month(Cell which contains the date)` and use this new column to filter the pivot table by months.

Comment: Sum of Qty2 Column Labels   
Row Labels Copy Editing Holiday - NB Indexing Internal Meetings - NB
Oct'17 22.04% 0.00% 0.00% 10.32%
Nov'17 20.18% 8.87% 0.00% 9.98%
Dec'17 20.84% 10.68% 0.00% 10.02%
Jan'18 31.01% 8.79% 0.00% 6.22%
Feb'18 31.03% 3.95% 1.46% 7.09%
March'18 41.45% 4.60% 0.00% 7.98%
April'18 36.10% 0.00% 0.00% 6.11%
May'18 32.17% 4.42% 0.00% 7.08%
June'18 28.85% 0.00% 0.00% 9.01%
July'18 34.94% 5.02% 0.00% 6.83%
August'18 31.69% 0.00% 0.00% 7.90%
September'18 25.36% 4.84% 7.26% 6.27%
:

Comment: My pivot table looks something like this. I need to sort the top 8 tasks by that respective month